# Campo String no MySQL retorna como tipo bytearray utilizando Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Ao realizar uma consulta no MySQL usando Python, obtenho um retorno do tipo bytearray, sendo que a coluna é do tipo String.

```
import mysql.connector as myc

# conexão MySQL
conMySQL = myc.connect (host = 'localhost',user = 'root',password = 'mysql',database = 'teste')

cursorMySQL = conMySQL.cursor()
sqlMySQL = """SELECT
  f.fid,
  f.uri,
  n.nid AS FK_REGISTRO_VIRTUAL
FROM field_data_field_anexos a
JOIN node n ON a.entity_id = n.nid
JOIN file_managed f ON a.field_anexos_fid = f.fid
WHERE n.`type` = 'registro_virtual' and f.fid = 76881;"""
cursorMySQL.execute(sqlMySQL)

result = cursorMySQL.fetchall()
for fid, uri, nid in result:
    print(fid ,'-', uri.decode('utf8'), '-', nid)

cursorMySQL.close()
conMySQL.close()
```

Segue o retorno:

> 76881 -
>   bytearray(b'public://privado/registro-virtual/2018/11/Audi\xc3\xaancia-cust\xc3\xb3dia-29-08-0007877-15.2017.815.2002.pdf')
>   - 65542

E ao substituir o `print(fid ,'-', uri, '-', nid)` por 
`print(fid ,'-', uri.decode('utf8'), '-', nid)`, obtenho o seguinte retorno:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xea' in
>   position 46: ordinal not in range(128)

Verifiquei que o decode('utf8') só funciona quando a string a ser tratada não vem diretamente do banco de dados.

Como posso resolver?

Comment: E o encoding da coluna é `utf8` mesmo? Já experimentou usar `latin1` ou `utf16`? Pois o erro é que a sequência de bytes não é uma string UTF8 válida, então talvez apenas não seja UTF8...

Comment: Já tentei usar latin1 e utf16 e também não funcionou. Quando ao charset da coluna e tabela ainda não sei qual é.

Comment: [Essa resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049958/1284458) tem as queries para você recuperar os charsets de tabelas, colunas e bancos de dados.

Comment: Descobri o tipo da coluna, é utf8_bin, só que ao alterar para print(fid ,'-', uri.decode('utf8_bin'), '-', nid) retorna LookupError: unknown encoding: utf8_bin

Comment: `utf8_bin` é o collation, isso significa que a coluna é `utf8` e as comparações desta coluna são feitas de forma binária. O que estou me perguntando é porque o python está usando o 'ascii' codec. O encode [funciona normalmente](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/MotionlessMysteriousTrialsoftware), talvez o problema seja em outra parte do código.

Comment: Também verifiquei no terminal e funciona, mas ao ler do banco não, inclusive outras colunas String ao ler do banco retorna o mesmo erro. Tentei ler uma coluna com o collation utf8_general_ci e ocorre o mesmo erro. Deve ter algum tratamento para ler String do database que eu não estou sabendo.

Comment: Então o mais aconselhável e procurar a documentação do _connector_ que você está usando.